# ServiceStack Razor Model Validation

Tags: servicestack

What's the best practice for returning validation errors to the view with the incorrect attempted values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service errors should automatically be populated in the View's `@ModelError` placeholder and you can access the `@ResponseStatus` property to get the populated typed ResponseStatus where the exception details are stored.